# Why does min still complain inside constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
using T = double;

int main()
{
    f();
}
void f() {
    T x = 2;
    if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        std::cout << std::min(static_cast<int64_t>(2), x);
    } else {
    std::cout << std::min(1.0, x);
    }
}
```

The compiler is explaining that

```
<source>:15:57: error: no matching function for call to 'min(int64_t, T&)'
```

I thought it wouldn't be a problem because when T is a double, the first branch won't be instantiated. Apparently my understanding is wrong. Could someone help point out where my understanding goes wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `f()` template, and `T` template parameter.

```
template <typename T>
void f() {
    T x = 2;
    if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        std::cout << std::min(static_cast<int64_t>(2), x);
    } else {
    std::cout << std::min(1.0, x);
    }
}
```

then

```
int main()
{
    f<double>();
}
```

For [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

(emphasis mine)

> If a constexpr if statement appears inside a templated entity, and if
> condition is not value-dependent after instantiation, the discarded
> statement is not instantiated when the enclosing template is
> instantiated .
>
> **Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive**:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     if constexpr(false) {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: No. My question is why `f()` without the template does not compile? I dont need an answer that works because I know how to make it work too.

Comment: @user122049 Explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a template, the "false" branch of a `constexpr if` clause is *discarded*, ***not ignored***. Thus, the code in such a branch must still be well-formed (and yours isn't, for the reason given).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr`
> is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) works with references. And both the arguments should be the same type. Since you're providing 2 different types, it cannot decide which one the argument type should be. You can work around that by explicitly specifying the type you like both the arguments to be converted:

```
std::min<double>(static_cast<int64_t>(2), x)
```

Be careful with dangling references.

The case when the failing branch of `if constexpr` doesn't matter is only in templates and `f` is not a template function.

Comment: But this statement `std::min(static_cast<int64_t>(2), x)` is in the branch that fails the constexpr check. Why does it matter if the overload cannot be resolved?

Comment: @user122049 Oh, you're misguided by that. The case when failing `constexpr` branch doesn't matter is only in templates, not plain functions.

Comment: `min` _is_ a template function.

Comment: @user122049 We're talking about the function which contains the `if constexpr`. In your case that's `f`. Make `f` a template and your code will compile fine.

Comment: Do you know why constexpr doesn't work in plain functions? This seems to be quite surprising.

Comment: @user122049 it makes more sense if you think about it. It's not dependent on any template arguments, so it can't be broken depending on the argument. If it's broken, it's always broken and you should either go fix your (broken) code or remove it.